# React & how to transfer event

Tags: reactjs, frontend

Can you help me to understand how to transfer the event from one component to another? I understand how it make it in own component but I surrendered my problem:(
Another word when I click on the button second component should render (display from "none" to "inline")

```js
var ComponentOne = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {property: false};
  },
  handleSearch: function() {
    this.setState({property: this.state.property ? false : true});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" className="component-one" onClick={this.handleClick}>(show full)</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ComponentTwo = React.createClass({
  style: function() {
    return (???????) ? {display: "inline"} : {display: "none"} //I don't understand how to realized this
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="component-two" style={this.style()}>Example</div>;
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
                // What properties?
  render: fucntion() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentOne /> //?
        <ComponentTwo /> //?
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

```css
.component-one, .component-two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need here is a component to play the middle man. You can make this middle man component a container component that holds and manipulates your state and then your other two components that you already have become stateless components. Like this:

```
var ComponentOne = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" className="component-one" onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>(show full)</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ComponentTwo = React.createClass({
  style: function() {
    return (this.props.showExample) ? {display: "inline"} : {display: "none"}
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="component-two" style={this.style()}>Example</div>
    );
  }
});

var Controller = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {property: false};
  },
  handleSearch: function() {
    this.setState({property: !this.state.property});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentOne clickHandler={this.handleSearch} />
        <ComponentTwo showExample={this.state.property}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
})

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Controller />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

By the way, I thought I should mention, doing it this way you could potentially make it so that in the Controller component you conditionally render ComponentTwo rather than using the style to hide it. I didn't want to change the styling functionality in case there was a specific reason you were doing but if there isn't then I'd say just only render Component2 if you need it.

Here is a fiddle of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/4rh31tou/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Zac! Good luck for you too! :)

Comment: @evgkch Have you had a chance to check if my answer was correct? If so  you might like to mark it as such. Cheers.